# not working order by in MS power query on accented letters

Tags: powerquery

I have power query in MS excel 2016, I order data by name, but I have accented letters š, č, ... which are now sorted to the end of dataset but should be for example š after s or č after c. Is it possible how to make some workaround here? I guess maybe change encoding, but I can't find how.

```
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{{"Name", Order.Ascending}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do this is to create a calculated column where you replace those special values and then sort on that column.

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each Text.Replace(Text.Replace([Name],"š","sz"),"č","cz")),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort("Added Custom",{{{"Custom", Order.Ascending}})
```

Once you've sorted, then you can delete that column.

Answer (score 0):

I used your logic Alexis but add one step - lowercased the column. Also I replaced more values. So I'm posting it in case somebody is interested. Thanks a lot Alexis!

```
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each [Name]),
#"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom2",{{"Custom", Text.Lower, type text}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(#"Lowercased Text","á","az",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}),"č","cz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}),"ď","dz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "é","ez",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ě","ez",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "í","iz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ň","nz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ó","oz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ř","rz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "š","sz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ť","tz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ú","uz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ů","uz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ý","yz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}), "ž","zz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Custom"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Replaced Value",{{"Custom", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Custom"})
```